# Mobs living in the physics engine

Tags: physics-engine, control

So, yeah. Mobs (including, and indeed especially, the player), physics engine running (cannon.js), first-person perspective, fairly low-poly-count world because I'm targeting WebGL. I'm *trying* to represent my mobs within the physics engine, moving them by applying forces or impulses, and I'm having some problems:

1) Ramps! The FPS Way seems to be that critters run uphill and downhill and on the flat, all at the same speed. But of course even-slightly-realistic physics really wants you to go slower uphill, especially if you add friction to prevent "standing" mobs from sliding downhill. I've tried compensating for this by calculating how fast the mob "wants" to go, and applying force proportionate to the difference between its actual velocity and desired velocity, but it just Ain't Right. Also, the mobs have a tendency to jump up off the top of staircases.

2) Falling over! To make the mobs collide with things, they have to be represented by some appropriate shape. I've tried a few different ones. Particles are an obvious lose, and fall into every possible crack in the geometry. A box the approximate shape of the bounding box for a standing person falls over constantly, especially on slopes. Putting the center of mass for the object at the bottom of the box helps, but only somewhat. Using a lower, flatter shape-- think "coin with beveled edges"-- prevents the falling down, but fails at detecting collisions. The last thing I tried was a sort of egg shape, which stays up but staggers like a drunken sailor.

Obviously, I'm missing something. What? Do people just have to have Special Physics Of Their Own? Should I toss the whole thing and write that car game instead?

Comment: You likely won't be able to solve (2) without some artificial constraints. That's what we do in real life as well, making constant ajustments using our muscles, just to keep balanced.

Comment: to 2), just prevent the character to change its y axe.

Comment: cannon.js doesn't have "keep this vertical"... but it *does* have "keep this local vector in THIS body orthogonal to this local vector in this OTHER body"... named "RotationalEquation" of all things. Two of 'em, hooked to a static body with a nice horizontal orientation, might do the job. Off to try it!